# DIsplay rows in a table by substituting value for a given column

Tags: java, jdbc

I have two tables departments and employees both have common column department_id

First I displayed department name from departments table second employee_id from employees table. now my query is I want to get department name from user and compare with department table, if name is available result should display employee id for that particular department

```
    import java.sql.*;
    class OracleCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       try {
        //step1 load the driver class   
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
        //step2 create the connection object 
           Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hr","hr"); 
        //step3 create the statement object 
           Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from departments");
          while (rs.next()) {
            String dname = rs.getString("DEPARTMENT_NAME");
            System.out.println(dname);
          }

      Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("select * from employees");
      while (rs1.next()) {
         Integer eno = rs1.getInt("employee_id");
         System.out.println(eno);

      } 
       con.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: import java.sql.*;
class OracleCon
{  
public static void main(String args[])
{  
try
{ 
//step1 load the driver class 
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
//step2 create  the connection object  
Connection con=
DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hr","hr");  
//step3 create the statement object
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from departments");
while(rs.next())
{
String dname=rs.getString("DEPARTMENT_NAME");
System.out.println(dname);     
}

Comment: Statement stmt1=con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs1=stmt1.executeQuery("select * from employees");
while(rs1.next()) 
{ 
Integer eno=rs1.getInt("employee_id");
System.out.println(eno); 
} 
con.close();   
}
catch(Exception e)
{ 
System.out.println(e);
}  
}  
}

Comment: snippets you posted as comments are fully unreadable (maybe Jon Skeet is able to read this, but most users here are not). Edit your question to add them in question body, properly formatted.

Comment: Why don't do this in a single SQL request using a Join ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your employees and department tables have a foreign-key relationship (or a logical key relationship) such that employees.department_name = department.department_name. A simple database join should get the job done.

Also, if you want to search by department name (or any other variable), use a PreparedStatement, not a Statement.

```
String sql = "select e.* from employee e,  department d where d.department_name = ? and d.department_name=e.deparment.name"); )// ? will be replaced by a parameter obtained from a user

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString(1, deptName); //deptName is obtained from the user

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
.....
```